# App breaks when distributed with test flight

Tags: ios, testflight

The app I am working on has one screen that requires a lot of network traffic. When I build the app and install it on my iPhone it works without problems. When I distribute the app via TestFlight the app crashes on the screen, on exactly the same iPhone. The problem first surfaced when I refactored the code, but when I went back to the old situation. The problem was still there.

The crash report gives to little information to work with. I would like to reproduce the test flight problem. But running the code on Xcode just works fine, even when I restart the app with the phone not con Any pointers on how to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you build with symbols?

Comment: Does a release build work?

Comment: So you had a version that worked, you made a change and it broke, you removed the change and it is still broken - sure that undoing the change made it to TestFlight?

Comment: Same thing happens here. It runs ok in the simulator / device using a development provisioning file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the newest Xcode update (7.1.1) introduced this.

I just made a build using 7.1 and it worked perfectly.

Hope it works!

Comment: Ah thanks, I was still running Xcode 7.1. So that can't be it.